# How do inward rectifier potassium channels work in the heart?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, cell-membrane, electrophysiology

Apparently in cardiomyocytes, there is an inward rectifying potassium channel that operates during phase 4 of the cardiomyocyte action potential.  I have heard that despite this potassium channel being referred to as an *inward rectifying channel*, that *in vitro* the channel in fact still transports potassium from the inside to the outside of the cell.  It appears that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inward-rectifier_potassium_ion_channel) seems to suggest otherwise (?).

Can someone please explain what the inward rectifier potassium channel does and its role in phase 4 of the myocyte action potential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Boron's medical physiology textbook:

> "Although inward rectifying potassium channels pass current better in
>   the inward than the outward direction, the membrane potential (Vm) is
>   typically never more negative than Ek (equilibrium potential of potassium across the membrane). Thus,net inward K+ current does
>   not occur physiologically. As a result, the activation of GIRK
>   channels (G protein coupled inwardly rectifying potassium channel)
>   hyperpolarizes cardiac cells by increasing K+ conductance or outward
>   K+ current."